# Create Microsoft Teams Meeting invite programatically using graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to create Teams Meeting invite via graph API but unable to figure out how to send meeting participants via the body as their documentation is not clear. I was using the graph API `/me/onlineMeetings` as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) with the following body. I am not sure if this is the correct way, All I know is meeting timings, participant email ids. Can someone help me here?

Post request body:

```
{
    "startDateTime":"2021-05-13T10:30:34.2444915-07:00",
    "endDateTime":"2021-05-13T10:35:34.2464912-07:00",
    "subject":"Testing Invite",
    "meetingParticipants": {
          "attendees": [{
                "mail": "test@outlook.com"
          }]
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To specify presenters and/or attendants please use the below structure.
To find additional information , please refer to the [onlineMeeting Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeeting?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties), and click though to the sub-objects such as attendees.

AFAIK you can not use the API to add presenters / attendees later.

```json
{
  "startDateTime": "{{startDateTime}}",
  "endDateTime": "{{endDateTime}}",
  "subject": "Meeting with {{Attendee_upn}} regarding {{$randomBs}}",
  "autoAdmittedUsers": "EveryoneInCompany",
  "participants": {
    "organizer": {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "upn": "jos@jvteams.xyz"
        }
      }
    },
    "attendees": [
      {
        "upn": "{{Attendee_upn}}",
        "identity": {
          "user": {
            "id": "{{Attendee_id}}"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually the 
```        "identity": {
          "user": {
            "id": "{{Attendee_id}}"
          }
``` 
part is optional

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can using graph API.
You need to update your meeting. Please refer to this [Update onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

You need to update ***participants*** property to add/remove attendees.

**NOTE** You can only modify the attendees field. You cannot update organizer field of the participants property.